# how to uninstall conan deployed data

Tags: conan

Here is the setup: I'm building a CPP library using my own Makefile. I want to package the shared objects and the include files in a Conan package, so I can offer it to the users to directly install the binaries (without having to recompile from sources).

One problem that I had was to deploy the content in *user space* (`/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/include/<lib>`), but I figured this out by adding a `deploy()` method in the `conanfile.py` recipe. It comes with the disadvantage that the data is now duplicated (both in conan cache and in user space), but let's save this issue for another discussion.

The question I ask now is how to remove the deployed data (from `/usr/local/lib`, ...) when uninstalling the Conan package?

I have verified it, `conan remove <package>` does not remove the deployed data, only the data from `.conan` cache.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to provide .o files or executables? It's not clear. If .o, why? It's a bad idea, why not provide final binaries instead?

Comment: Conan packages are not intended to be installed into system paths.  It looks like you are using Conan incorrectly.

Comment: @uilianries, neither of those, I was talking about .so (shared objects -> libraries) and include files.

Comment: @John, I agree I am not using it perhaps as it was intended, but it does support deploying files, so the simple fact that when you uninstall the package, the deployed files stay there, I find it a little bit weird.

Comment: Indeed Conan is package manager focused for development, but as deploy generator allows you copying file to the system, you can install wherever you want. And, shared libraries are totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question I ask now is how to remove the deployed data (from /usr/local/lib, ...) when uninstalling the Conan package?

There is no such feature. But, you can ask for it [here](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues). It's a bit complicated, as Conan would need to cache deployed paths.

Comment: ok, that explains why I didn't find anything about this in the documentation.